# Time not changing when in a windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a script that downloads files from an s3 bucket and I want to log the time it takes.  So I have a for loop that goes through each s3 file and then if the size is greater that a set value I download the file.  From within the if statement I echo out a line that includes the name of the file and the time.  The problem is the time value does not change.  I have created a very simple example that shows the issue.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%

set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%

cd C:\Users\Public\code
echo %time% %date%> Outside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log
timeout /t 10
echo %time% %date%>> Outside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log
timeout /t 10
echo %time% %date% - Welcome Here>> Outside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log
timeout /t 10
echo %time% %date% - Welcome Here Again>> Outside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log
if not exist "1.txt" (
   echo %time% %date%> Inside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log
   timeout /t 10
   echo %time% %date%>> Inside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log
   timeout /t 10
   echo %time% %date% - Welcome Here>> Inside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log
   timeout /t 10
   echo %time% %date% - Welcome Here Again>> Inside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log
)
```

So how do I get the Outside_IF to work in Inside_IF

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: In cmd it is %. In .bat file it is %% instead of %, so `call echo Date time: %%date%% %%time%%` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when your parenthesised block of code is initially parsed, any variables are expanded then, not when the lines of code within it are actually run. *(That is why you should see each '%TIME%' value as exactly the same)*. As you've already enabled delayed expansion, you need to use it in order for those values to be evaluated when the lines are run instead.

Example:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%G In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe \: . /NJH /L ^
     ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe " 123"'
) Do Set "SUBFILENAME=%%G%%H%%I"

CD /D "%PUBLIC%\code" 2> NUL || GoTo :EOF

1> "Outside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log" Echo %TIME% %DATE%
"%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe" /T 10
1>> "Outside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log" Echo %TIME% %DATE%
"%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe" /T 10
1>> "Outside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log" Echo %TIME% %DATE% - Welcome Here
"%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe" /T 10
1>> "Outside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log" Echo %TIME% %DATE% - Welcome Here Again

If Not Exist "1.txt" (
    1> "Inside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log" Echo !TIME! !DATE!
    "%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe" /T 10
    1>> "Inside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log" Echo !TIME! !DATE!
    "%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe" /T 10
    1>> "Inside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log" Echo !TIME! !DATE! - Welcome Here
    "%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe" /T 10
    1>> "Inside_IF_%SUBFILENAME%.log" Echo !TIME! !DATE! - Welcome Here Again
)
```